# how to print complete function excerpts of program containing some specific pattern inside

Tags: python, linux, grep

I have a file having thousand of functions starting with <\registername> and ending with <\regend>. Fie has few of the function with a specific pattern and most function doesn't have that pattern inside them. I only want output code with that specific pattern inside of them. 
I have an input program like below:-

func3 and func5 code not needed in the output file.

```
<registername> func1<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>

<registername> func2<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>

<registername> func3<\registername>
<var>...
<no_pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>

<registername> func4<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>

<registername> func5<\registername>
<var>...
<no_pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>


<registername> func1<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>

<registername> func2<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>

<registername> func4<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>
```

Comment: Do you want to achive your purpose with `python` or with `grep`? They are different things. You may firstly select lines inside the functions (as lines between two patterns), and then find another pattern among these selected lines.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/\n<pattern>/' file
<registername> func1<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>

<registername> func2<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>

<registername> func4<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>
```

or:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '!/<no_pattern>/' file
<registername> func1<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>

<registername> func2<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>

<registername> func4<\registername>
<var>...
<pattern> are you good <pattern>
<\regend>
```

If neither of those are what you want then update your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.